# An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm studying the book of 'Pro Asp.net MVC5'. I'm following the example in this book.

The error happens on Binding Data from Mock to localDb which is the example of Chapter 7.4.5

the crash screenshot is here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO1c3.png)

scroll down
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yputm.png)
and the detail is

'{"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:\r\n\r\nSportsStore.Domain.Concrete.Product: : EntityType 'Product' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nProducts: EntityType: EntitySet 'Products' is based on type 'Product' that has no keys defined.\r\n"}'

```
private void AddBindings()
    {
        //Mock<IProductsRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductsRepository>();
        //mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new List<Product>{
        //    new Product { Name = "Football", Price = 25 },
        //    new Product { Name = "Surf board", Price = 179 },
        //    new Product { Name = "Running shoes", Price = 95 }
        //    });
        //kernel.Bind<IProductsRepository>().ToConstant(mock.Object);
        kernel.Bind<IProductsRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();
    }
```

The code which I commented works well while the uncommented code will lead to crash.
Crash triggered on List.cshtml. the line `foreach(var p in Model)`
I know it could be the localDb's problem but I don't know how to debug it and fix it.
The connectingString in Web.config is as following.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

localDb screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyeMc.png)

VS DB settings screenshots
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQQ0B.png)

models

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProjecID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

the Stack Trace
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se9hE.png)

Comment: Where is the connection string and exception details? Include them both to find out source of your issue.

Comment: here it is now.

Comment: "One or more validation errors were detected..." => can you show what validation errors occurred? How your model class looks like?

Comment: it just shows 'one or more validation errors were detected.' I believe the model class can't get data from localDb.

Comment: Try pushing the scroll bar down and see the text under it, or click "View Detail" and point to both "Inner Exception" and "Stack Trace", then edit your question with copied all exception info. With detailed message it becomes easier to find the problem source.

Comment: I know the problem now after following your steps. Thank you Tetsuya. It has been fixed.